# How to create comment object type to todos object using graphql and react?

Tags: node.js, parsing, reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I am making a simple react-native app based on todos sample app. GraphQL and parse are used to manage data. I am trying to modify the schema and add a comment object to the todo objects but not sure what is the best way to do it.

How can I make it so when I add a new comment with a supplied todo id then it adds under the todo item?

I appreciate any help to fix comment object schema and add comment mutation.

```
const TODOS = Parse.Object.extend('Todos');


let getTodos = (status, context) => {
    console.log("context: " + JSON.stringify(context));
    let q = new Parse.Query(TODOS);
    if (status !== undefined && status.toLowerCase() !== 'any')
    {
        q.startsWith("status", status);
    }
    return q.find();
};

let getTodo = (id) => {
    let q = new Parse.Query(TODOS);
    return q.get(id);
};

 const todoType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Todo',
    description: 'Todo type',
    fields: () =>({
        id: globalIdField('Todo'),
        _id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
            resolve: (obj) => obj.id
        },
        title: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: (obj) => obj.get('title')
        },
        completed: {
            type: GraphQLBoolean,
            resolve: (obj) => obj.get('completed')
        }
    }),
    interfaces: [nodeDefs.nodeInterface]
});

const todoConnection = connectionDefinitions({
    name: 'Todo',
    nodeType: todoType
});

let viewerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Viewer',
    fields: () => ({
        id: globalIdField("Viewer"),
        todoConnection: {
            type: todoConnection.connectionType,
            args: {
                status: {
                    type: GraphQLString,
                    defaultValue: 'any'
                },
                ...connectionArgs
            },
            resolve: (_, {status, ...args}, context) => {
                return connectionFromPromisedArray(getTodos(status, context), args)
            }
        },
    }),
    interfaces: [nodeDefs.nodeInterface]
});
```

I tried to add following to todoType in fields object but I am not sure if it would work.

```
        comment:{
            type: commentConnection.connectionType,
            args: {
                status: {
                    type: GraphQLString,
                    defaultValue: 'any'
                },
                ...connectionArgs
            },
            resolve: (_, {status, ...args}, context) => {
                return connectionFromPromisedArray(getComments(status, context), args)
            }
        }
```

Where

```
     let getComments = (status, context) => {
    console.log("context: " + JSON.stringify(context));
    let c = new Parse.Query(COMMENTS);
    if (status !== undefined && status.toLowerCase() !== 'any')
    {
        c.startsWith("status", status);
    }
    return c.find({ sessionToken: context.parseSessionToken });
};

let getComment = (id) => {
    let c = new Parse.Query(COMMENTS);
    return c.get(id);
};
 const commentType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Comment',
    description: 'Comment type',
    fields: () =>({
        id: globalIdField('Comment'),
        _id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
            resolve: (obj) => obj.id
        },
        comment: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: (obj) => obj.get('comment')
        }
    }),
    interfaces: [nodeDefs.nodeInterface]
});

const commentConnection = connectionDefinitions({
    name: 'Comment',
    nodeType: commentType
});
```

Here is the graphql query:

```
  query{
      viewer{
             todoConnection {
             edges 
             {
                node {
                   id,
                   title,
                   comment {

                     edges
                         {
                         node{
                          id,
                          comment
                          }
                        }
                      }
                   }
                }
              }
           }
        }
```

And this is todo mutation:

```
let addTodoMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
    name: 'AddTodo',

    inputFields: {
        title: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    },

    outputFields: {
        todoEdge: {
            type: todoConnection.edgeType,
            resolve: (obj) => ({node: obj, cursor: obj.id})
        },
        viewer: {
            type: viewerType,
            resolve: () => viewer
        }
    },

    mutateAndGetPayload: ({title}) => {
        let newTodo = new TODOS();
        newTodo.set('title', title);
        newTodo.set('completed', false);
        return newTodo.save();
    }
});
```

Comment: If I resume, you are trying to achieve a "CommentTodo" mutation ?

Comment: That is right @whitep4nther